# Microsoft Visual Studio, how to code so that a ASCII will display on my console application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ascii, console-application

I want to incorporate an ASCII image as it can be seen [here](http://chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=logos%20and%20insignias/jolly%20roger) or something like that, on my console application but I am not sure how to get it in there I have been trying:

```
console.writeline("");
```

but that does not seem to work.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` is the way to output to the console. I can't guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't working?

Comment: i cant because when i copy and paste the ASCII it comes up in just letters like if you look at the link im trying to console.writeline(" insert the ASCCI") but i just get loads of errors, and this is the only way i think you can put a logo/image kind of thing in a console application

Comment: Please spend some time and make this coherent. "that does not seem to work", "I just get loads of errors". Computers are very particular and emit precise error messages. Please learn to quote those error messages when asking for help.

Comment: Quick thing to try, put an @ before the leading double-quote of the string. This tells the compiler that this string contains no escape sequences and to treat it exactly as typed in. If you're using ASCII characters for art, it's highly recommended.

Comment: Why the skull?  Smells a bit like malware / cracking / dodgy stuff in general?  Or am I missing the fun of 'real' (pegleg) pirates?

Comment: got it working now, the @ worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
Console.WriteLine(@"                             ud$$$**$$$$$$$bc.");
Console.WriteLine(@"                          u@**""        4$$$$$$$Nu");
Console.WriteLine(@"                        J                ""#$$$$$$r");
Console.WriteLine(@"                       @                       $$$$b");
Console.WriteLine(@"                     .F                        ^*3$$$");
Console.WriteLine(@"                    :% 4                         J$$$N");
Console.WriteLine(@"                    $  :F                       :$$$$$");
Console.WriteLine(@"                   4F  9                       J$$$$$$$");
Console.WriteLine(@"                   4$   k             4$$$$bed$$$$$$$$$");
```

works for me.  I added an @ before the strings to disable escape characters and I had to double up any quotes so that they did not get interpreted as the end of the string.

So, if you write

```
Console.WriteLine("\n");
```

then that gets interpreted as a newline.  But

```
Console.WriteLine(@"\n");
```

will emit `\n` to the console.

Similarly you can't write

```
Console.WriteLine(@" u@**"    ");
```

That's probably the cause of the errors you have seen. Hence you would write:

```
Console.WriteLine(@" u@**""    ");
```

Anyway, although that makes it work it's much better to put the ASCII art in a text file or a resource and get at it that way – that avoids all these pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

If the ascii image is stored in a file you could use a stream reader and Console.WriteLine().  Make sure you check your code for case-sensitivity.  console.writeline(""); is not the same as Console.WriteLine("");.